# How to send list using curl?

Tags: java, curl

The backend is coded like this:

```
  @POST
  @Path("/resource")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response dailyBilling(
      final List<String> students)
      throws Exception {
     ....
  }
```

How should I send curl data, which would me accepted as a List on backend ?

Using the following curl i get 400:

```
curl --digest -u ameya379+beet@gmail.com:credentials\
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'\
-X POST -d '{"student1", "student2"}'\
http://localhost:8080/api/somepath/resource
```

Error:

```
{
    "detail":"Received JSON does not match expected format.",
    "error":400,
    "errorCode":"INVALID_JSON",
    "parameters":[],
    "reason":"Bad Request"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are encoded between `[]` in JSON.

```
curl  --digest -u ameya379+beet@gmail.com:credentials  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '["student1", "student2"]' http://localhost:8080/api/somepath/resource
```